# Why following c++11 program crash visual studio 2013 expresss edition?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, initializer-list

Following is the program which is leading to VS2013 express edition to crash. The same program does compile and run successfully on gcc4.8. It appears to me it is VS bug.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

struct x
{
public:
    std::string s{};
    //Does not crash if we replace above line with below one
    //std::string s{"VS2013"};
    int i{10};
public:
    x()  = default;
    ~x() = default;
    x(const x& rhs) = default;
    x& operator=(const x& rhs) = default;
};


int main()
{
    x a;
    std::cout << a.s << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to know that whether my assumption is correct or i am missing something.

Comment: A program that crashes has a bug. VS2013 is a program. VS2013 crashes. Therefore VS2013 has a bug. We don't need to look at your program, or know whether it resembles valid C++ code, to conclude that.

Comment: Not sure what answer you expect to this, of course the code is valid. Most (all?) things involving list initialization has been buggy in MSVC, so it's no surprise the compiler crashes. Thankfully, the workaround is simple in this case, just omit the braces.

Comment: To be clear, is it VS2013 itself that crashes (when you compile the code), or the program itself when you run it? In either case, is there an error message? If so, please include that message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest service pack for vs 2013. It should go away.